# Cancel Business Page Developer Account

Tags: facebook

I recently set up a business page for my company. I then registered as a developer from that id which was confirmed via my cell phone. I have since found out, (no thanks to any information on the Facebook site), that a business page can not create apps. I must have a personal account to develop apps using the SDK. I have a personal account that is listed as an administrator of my business page. But facebook is making me re-register as a developer from my personal account to access the developer sites. The problem is I have already used my cellphone number when I previously registered with my business page. How can I cancel the developer account linked to my business page so I can re-register as my personal account using my one and only cellphone number?